# JavaScript can't access my query API

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, jsonp

I built an app with Google App Engine that:

1. Queries a URL (e.g. `http://myapp.appspot.com/query?name="SomeName"&start_date="2012-01-01"`)
2. Receives a JSON response. This JSON response contains data from my *own* datastore within the same domain.
3. Plots a chart using that response.

The `app.yaml` configuration has the following lines:

```
- url: /.*
  script: main.py
```

Where in `main.py`, I assigned the URL `query` to be handled by the class `QueryHandler`.

All is well and good if I run the app online. However, I cannot receive a JSON response if I run the app using the offline development server.

When testing offline, I also duplicate my online datastore into the offline development server. I can confirm that it works well because I have other scripts that query into it and they work fine. The only problem is the JavaScript chart.

### Attempted solutions

1. If I change the query URL to `http://localhost:8080/query?name="SomeName"&start_date="2011-01-01"`, the chart renders fine.
2. If I insist on the querying the URL on the cloud `http://myapp.appspot.com/query?name="SomeName"&start_date="2012-01-01"`, I cannot render the chart.

### Objective

I'd like to be able to query the cloud URL at all times, without having to change the domain to `localhost`. This will be useful to me in the long run when I decide to open up a public API. Is there a way to do that? Or is this just a limitation on the development server?

Comment: See [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: Thank you for the tip @DanielRoseman, I've learned something new. If that's the case, is there a way to work around that?

Comment: @Kit Yes - look into JSONP. It's a trivial change, and JQuery supports the calling convention natively.

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript should always query back to the server from where it was loaded.

Use `window.location.hostname` and `window.location.port` to get the host & port of origin server.

Answer (score 1):

As you are apparently in control of the server who generates the JSON, you might workaround [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) by serving JSONP which is not much additional work.
Just check for a callback parameter and wrap your output within the fucntionname passed as callback. See [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

Comment: From my understanding, JSONP goes like this. I code my Client __HTML__ (using the `<script>` tag) so that it says, "Hey Server, give me the JavaScript function called Foo. I'll process it here in the client side myself." JavaScript will see it as a function, but as a human, I know better that it's just my required data __wrapped__ inside a function. Therefore I can write other JavaScript code to process it accordingly. Is that correct?

Comment: You actually add a script element with src referring to the query on your server: <script src="your_server?q=1....">. So source will be returning something like function_call_defined_in_callback({your_datastructure}); Only thing left for you is to process the payload by implementing "function_call_defined_in_callback".